# How can I get field names List for a custom setting

Tags: apex, customsetting

> I want a list of field names (List of Strings) for a custom setting, something like we get in Schema.DescribeFieldResult. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: You can this URL http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118709/how-to-retrieve-fields-of-custom-setting-in-apex-controller?rq=1 Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Describe Information works just fine for custom settings.

If you have a custom setting named mySetting__c then:

```
Set<String> flds = mySetting__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
```

will return a set of Field names for the custom setting